# Append problems after a linked list node delete

Tags: c

I can append, display, modify, delete and search in my linked list nodes. Deleting works well, but when I want to append after that, it seems to overwrite (or delete a node).

Lets say I have:

A - B - C nodes

I delete the B node. After that it looks like: A - C.
I want to append a D node to look like this: A - C - D.

But, instead it looks like this: A - D

What could be the problem here?

The whole project is pretty big, but the delete look like this:

```
    for ( ; llist->next != NULL; llist = llist->next)
   {
      if(strcmp(text, llist->book)==0)
      {
         break;
      }
      prev = llist;
   }

    if ( llist != NULL )
     {
      if ( llist == head)
      {
         head = llist->next;
      }
      else
      {
         prev->next= llist->next;
      }

      free(llist);
      printf("The %s string has been deleted!\n", text);
    }
```

The append code looks like this:

```
 while(getline(text,MAX)) 

    {

    if(!(llist = (struct lib*)malloc(sizeof(struct lib)))) { /*mem allocation*/
            break;
        }

        if(head) {
            prev->next= llist;
        } else {
            head= llist;
        }
        prev = llist;

    llist -> next= NULL;


    while(!textcheck(text))
    {
    printf("Please retype the name in the correct format: ");
    getline(text, MAX);
    }

    strcpy(llist->author, text); //hozzáírunk a láncolt listához

    printf("Please type the title of the book: ");
    getline(text, MAX);
    strcpy(llist->book,text);


    printf("Please type the release date: ");


    getline(szoveg, MAX);

    while(!yearcheck(text)) {
    printf("Please type a year between 1500 and 2016: ");
    getline(text, MAX);

    }
    num = atoi(text);

    llist->year = num;


    printf("Please type a topic: \n");
    printf("Topics: SciFi, Haboru, Fantasy,\nEletrajz, Ismeretterjeszto, Thriller, Akcio\n");


    strcpy(llist->tema, text);
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If the record is found at the first node, 'prev' is uninitialized?

Comment: Also............debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take your example of `A-B-C`. From the first loop, prev will be `A` once it deletes the node `B`:

```
for ( ; llist->next != NULL; llist = llist->next) 

{

if(strcmp(text, llist->book)==0){
    break;
}
prev = llist;

}
```

After that when it comes to append it is updating  with:

```
if(head){
    prev->next= llist;
}
```

which means `A`'s next will point to `D` instead of `C`. Hence `C`'s reference is lost and final list will look like `A-D`.

Comment: I see. But how can I fix the linkage?

Comment: If you want to append the new node in the end, before append traverse the entire list so that prev will always point to last node.

Comment: Traverse with for ( ; llist->next != NULL; llist = llist->next) ; right after this llist -> next= NULL; code?

Comment: llist = prev ;
for ( ; llist->next != NULL; llist = llist->next)
   {
      prev = llist;
   }

Comment: Unfortunately, that did the same thing. :(

Comment: edited the previous code for last statement: llist = prev ; for ( ; llist->next != NULL; llist = llist->next) { prev = llist; }prev=llist;